# Printing dictionary keys based on value

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello all. I am studying for my cs final and dictionaries are in there. i know dictionaries well, but this one has me stumped. how would i go about solving such a question?

> Given the dictionary below, continue to write code (old style, no functions required) that will produce a list of all the keys for which the values are in the range 1 to 100 inclusive. Do not hardcode your program for the given dictionary.

```
D = {1:1000, 2:2000, 3:3000, 1111:10, 2222:20, 3333:30}
```

Yes, this is an actual review question but this isn't homework.

I was thinking that I should do a for loop through the dictionary but that would not help because the `dict` is stored `key:value` and i really need to compare the `value` only.

Anything is appreciated!

Comment: But then again you do need the keys because you want to collect them in a list - so where's the problem? Just iterate over the dictionary (hint: use `D.items()` (Python 3)), check each value, and add the key to the list if the value falls within the range.

Comment: you can filter dict.items(), a list (or view in 3.x) of key, value pairs

Comment: In python2 maybe would be better to use dict.iteritems().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[k for k, v in D.items() if 1 <= v <= 100]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

```
>>> D = {1:1000, 2:2000, 3:3000, 1111:10, 2222:20, 3333:30}
>>> [key for key in D if 1 <= D[key] <= 100]
[3333, 2222, 1111]
```

Comment: @TimPietzcker Sorry about that, thanks for spotting it, I game in a previous console log, and not the one that I was actually trying to post! :P

Comment: ahhh yes this is great too!

Answer (score 1):

i think i actually figured it out!

i didnt use comprehension because my professor never went over it for whatever reason.

```
d ={1:1000, 2:2000, 3:3000, 1111:10, 2222:20, 3333:30}

for key in d:
    if d[key] >=1 and d[key] <=100:
        print(key)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: This is the simplest, but comprehensions are faster.

Comment: definitely. is there anything complex to comprehension that i need to know before doing? my professor has never gone over it but i see it all the time on stack and it seems far better

Comment: Nope, there's nothing complex about it. They are faster because of their implementation in native language code. You just write the `for` loops as you would have written in a normal way. You can also add multiple `if-else` statements. They are very handy as you can write a one-liner. Kinda cool too! :)

Comment: ok well thats good then, ill work on comprehension after my final then! Thanks!